# wp_update_post function ignores HTML tags

Tags: plugins, wp-update-post

I have a custom plugin that moves posts from one category to another and then inserts text after the post is moved.  This works fine except for I am trying to insert some CSS like you see below in the $start_text variable.  The wp_update_post function is stripping out the `<style type='text/css'>` tags completely and treating the contents withing the style tags as simple text.  How do I make sure those are kept in place when the function runs so the page uses the style I'm trying to import into the post?

**Variable:**

```
$start_text="<style type='text/css'>#footerlink { display:none; }</style>Beginning Of posts\n";
```

**The actual Wordpress function:**

```
function mohit_cron_hook_action(){
$my_query22 = new WP_Query;
    global $start_text;
    global $catfrom;
    global $catto;
    global $dayago;

                    $old_cat = $catfrom;
                    $new_cat = absint($catto);
                    $posts   = $my_query22->query(array('category__in'=>$old_cat, 'post_type'=>'post', 'nopaging'=>'true','date_query' => array('column' => 'post_date_gmt','before'  => $age)));
                    $posts8777=$posts;
                    print_r($posts8777);
                    foreach ($posts as $post) {

                        $current_cats = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
                        $current_cats = array_diff($current_cats, $old_cat);
                        if ($new_cat != -1) {
                            $current_cats[] = $new_cat;
                        }

                        if (count($current_cats) == 0) {
                            $current_cats = array(get_option('default_category'));
                        }
                        $current_cats = array_values($current_cats);
                        wp_update_post(array('ID'=>$post->ID,'post_category'=>$current_cats,'post_content'=>$start_text.get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID)));
                    }

 }
```

Comment: This is a known feature, that originates from the `current_user_can( 'unfiltered_html' )` check in the `kses_init()` function. This check fails for wp_cron calls when there's no user logged in. So try to search this site for possible workarounds, must be various methods available. But maybe you could solve this differently than inject an inline CSS into the post content? It sounds rather inflexible to do so!

Comment: Got it, thanks.  Yes, it's ugly but the application is very specific so it wont' require much additional after this is working.

Comment: I did find this link which I am experimenting with, hopefully it may help someone if they come across the same issue:  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_update_post-strips-css-id-attribute?replies=7

Comment: Ok great. You can always add your own answer and accept it (external links may disappear in the future) ;-) But this might also be closed as duplicate?

Comment: Why a duplicate @birgire?  Does stackexchange count wordpress.org posts as duplicate posts?

Comment: no, I just meant if a similar question is found here on [wordpress.se] ;-) (there might be few candidates in the Related box here on the right side)